# Pandas Merging two dataframes with joining on date between dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge, timedelta

Have quite interesting case.

There is `df_1` with `time` column based on low-granularity data (2s) like this:

```
2018-08-31 22:59:47.980000+00:00    41.77   
2018-08-31 22:59:49.979000+00:00    42.76   
2018-08-31 22:59:51.979000+00:00    40.86   
2018-08-31 22:59:53.979000+00:00    41.83   
2018-08-31 22:59:55.979000+00:00    41.73   
2018-08-31 22:59:57.979000+00:00    42.71
```

Also there is `df_2` with labels for this data and `time` column on hour basis:

```
2018-08-31 22:00:00 0.0
2018-08-31 23:00:00 1.0
2018-09-01 00:00:00 0.0
2018-09-01 01:00:00 1.0
2018-09-01 02:00:00 0.0
```

I would like to merge `df_1` with `df_2` that time from df_1 would be between each two consecutive time rows in `df_2` (between one hour for giving the label). If I would have two time columns in `df_2` (like `startTime` and `endTime`) I would use `pandasql` and its opportunities:

```
import pandasql 

sqlcode = '''
select *
from df_1
inner join df_2 on df_1.time >= df_2.startTime and df_1.time <= df_2.endTime
'''

newdf = ps.sqldf(sqlcode,locals())
```

But in this case I only have one column. Is there any way to solve this problem in Pandas?

Comment: Could you add the screenshots as sample data in your question so we can copy?

Comment: Can you show us your sample data? (not pics)

Comment: If you're going for count, use [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by hour.

Comment: no problem, just added values

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `pd.merge_asof`problem, I create a keydat dual of dates in df2,in order to show which date we merge from df2

```
#df1.Date=pd.to_datetime(df1.Date)
#df2.Date=pd.to_datetime(df2.Date)
yourdf=pd.merge_asof(df1,df2.assign(keydate=df2.Date),on='Date',direction='forward')
yourdf
                     Date         ...                     keydate
0 2018-08-31 22:59:47.980         ...         2018-08-31 23:00:00
1 2018-08-31 22:59:49.979         ...         2018-08-31 23:00:00
2 2018-08-31 22:59:51.979         ...         2018-08-31 23:00:00
3 2018-08-31 22:59:53.979         ...         2018-08-31 23:00:00
4 2018-08-31 22:59:55.979         ...         2018-08-31 23:00:00
5 2018-08-31 22:59:57.979         ...         2018-08-31 23:00:00
[6 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: I guess the problem that there is 2s interval and merge_asof won't be suitable here. If it will be 1s then yes I think it can be used

Comment: @Keithx check tolerance in it , and pass your 2 s condition :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using workaround with splitting time into `date` and `hour` columns. Maybe not too fancy but it solves the deal and pretty straight-forward:

```
import pandasql as ps

df_1['date'] = [d.date() for d in df_1['time']]
df_1['time'] = df_1['time'].dt.round('H').dt.hour

df_2['date'] = [d.date() for d in df_2['time']]
df_2['time'] = df_2['time'].dt.round('H').dt.hour

sqlcode = '''
select *
from df_1
inner join df_2 on df_1.time=df_2.time and df_1.date=df_2.date
'''

newdf = ps.sqldf(sqlcode,locals())
```